# FastCGI process has failed frequently recently - for WP on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, fastcgi

We have a Windows 2008 R2 server. We have hosted WordPress website on it. The website shows 500 internal error frequently. On enabling the detail mode, it gave the following message:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>   The FastCGI process has failed frequently recently. Try the request again in a while.

Resetting the server starts the website.

The issue has been quite often and we are unable to find any further information regarding the cause. Neither we are able to replicate the issue.

We have enabled sysloging in php.ini but to no avail.

Comment: this issue still exists? I remember YT used have this issue often ...

Comment: Can you please share phpinfo details?

Comment: What about general windows logging? Event viewer and IIS request log \ exception log might be useful. anything special there?

Also, did you enable FastCGI php logging? `fastcgi.logging = 1` in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

**I have some Suggestions:**

1. You can Increase your php memory_limit at least 16M or more in php.ini.
2. you can check if there is some detailed messages in event log then you can figure out the issue.
3. you can switch to other php handlers like nginx or other.
4. In Some cases mysql processes occurs this type of issue. So check MySql processes of the server(Many times it gives timeout error but in some cases it gives error 500)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without log verbosity, but I had the same issue.  You can see if this works for you:

Try maximizing your "Instance MaxRequest" in your FASTCGI Configuration.

IIS `root > FastCGI Settings` : Thenchoose php-cgi.exe for WP, then `edit` and increase the Instance MaxRequests